# Check all lines in the file that have both, one or none of the strings in the same line

Tags: c++, string, fstream

I want to check if the chosen strings appear in the same line.
Sadly I don't get the correct output.
The file contains this text

```
/* one 
two
one two
two one
two 
one
something
else */



#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void display(ifstream& MyFile, string a, string b)
{
    string s="";
    int choice;
    cout << "Choose the mode you want to use " << endl;
    cout << "1. Find both words" << endl;
    cout << "2. Find one words" << endl;
    cout << "3. Find where there is none words" << endl;
    cout << "Choose the mode you want to use : ";
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        while (getline(MyFile, s))
        {
    
            if (s.find_first_of(a, 0) && (s.find_first_of(b, 0)) )
            {
                cout << "Found both words" << endl;  
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        while (getline(MyFile, s))
        {
            if ((s.find_first_of(a, 0)  && !s.find_first_of(b, 0)) || (!s.find_first_of(a, 0) && s.find_first_of(b, 0) ))
            {
                cout << "Found one word" << endl;
            }
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        while (getline(MyFile, s))
        {
            getline(MyFile, s);
            if (!s.find_first_of(a, 0) && !s.find_first_of(b, 0))
            {
                cout << "No words " << endl;
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Wrong Input" << endl;
    }
}

  
int main()
{
    ifstream Myfile("Mydata.dat");
    string a = "one", b = "two",fileData;
    display(Myfile, a, b);
    Myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I get "Found both words" 5 times whereas it should be 2. The same thing happens with the other options. My
thoughts are that in the `if` statement I compare the function `s.find_firstof(str, pos)` wrongly because this function returns the index of the first instance in `s` of any character in `str`, starting the search at position `pos`. My second thought is that I read the data of the file wrong.

```
Found both words
Found both words
Found both words
Found both words
Found both words
```

Comment: Are you sure about the `OR` in `s.find_first_of(a, 0) || (s.find_first_of(b, 0)` ? It seems to me like you would want _both_ conditions to be `true` to say that you've found both words.

Comment: If you review how your C++ textbook explains the return value from `find_first_of` the problem should be very obvious. `find_first_of` does ***NOT*** return true if the string was found. That's not what it returns. Besides, `find_first_of` is not the right way to search for a given word in the first place, since searching for the word "a" will find it five times in a line that contain a single word: "abracadabra". Would that be your expected result (assuming the return value is checked correctly)?

Comment: yes, you are right. I've changed that and now it outputs it 1 time.

Comment: Alright, then il try to find a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the `if` statement wrong.

I changed the way to verify if a string contains another one, basically `s.find(a)` will return the start position of a in s if it exists in it, or will return `-1` if it doesn't.
This way, verifying like this `s.find(a) != -1` or `s.find(a) <s.length()` would work the same way, bacause in conversion of -1 to int is the max of `size_t`

This should solve your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void display(ifstream &MyFile, string a, string b)
{
    string s = "";
    int choice;
    cout << "Choose the mode you want to use " << endl;
    cout << "1. Find both words" << endl;
    cout << "2. Find one words" << endl;
    cout << "3. Find where there is none words" << endl;
    cout << "Choose the mode you want to use : ";
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        while (getline(MyFile, s))
        {

            if (s.find(a) < s.length() && (s.find(b) < s.length()))
            {
                cout << "Found both words" << endl; // means that this line have BOTH words
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        while (getline(MyFile, s))
        {
            if (s.find(a) < s.length() || (s.find(b) < s.length()))
            {
                cout << "Found one word" << endl; //means that this line have at least one of the two words
            }
            /*
            if (s.find(a) < s.length() && (s.find(b) < s.length())) 
            {
                cout << "Found one word" << endl; //means that this line have the two words at the same time
            }
            */
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        while (getline(MyFile, s))
        {
            getline(MyFile, s);
            if (!s.find_first_of(a, 0) && !s.find_first_of(b, 0))
            {
                cout << "No words " << endl; // means that this line do not have ANY of the two words
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Wrong Input" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    ifstream Myfile("Mydata.dat");
    string a = "one", b = "two", fileData;
    display(Myfile, a, b);
    Myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The output ou this code is:

```
Choose the mode you want to use 
1. Find both words
2. Find one words
3. Find where there is none words
Choose the mode you want to use : 1
Found both words
Found both words
```

and

```
Choose the mode you want to use 
1. Find both words
2. Find one words
3. Find where there is none words
Choose the mode you want to use : 2
Found one word
Found one word
Found one word
Found one word
Found one word
Found one word
```

Comment: Taking your comments at face value: "find returns -1 if not found" then this logic is wrong "s.find(a) < s.length()" because  -1 will be < length. The test should just be `find() != npos` (don't use -1, use npos. no need to check against length - c++ isn't going give you a result beyond the end of the string)

Comment: Thank you for helping Rodrigo.

Comment: My problem was resolved! Thanks to everybody.

Comment: @Coder777 You accept a completely incorrect answer? I give up !

Answer (score 1):

Two obvious errors:

`find_first_of()` returns a `size_t` (position) not a bool. To check for success you need `find_first_of() != string::npos`

Assuming `find_first_of()` did return a `bool`:

```
if (s.find_first_of(a, 0) || (s.find_first_of(b, 0)) )
{
     cout << "Found both words" << endl;  
}
```

If you find either string then you found both? Wrong. You need `&&` (logical AND) not `||` (logical OR)

Ignoring the word vs string issue in the comments, I'd simplify your code by counting how many strings were found:

```
int num_words_found = 0;
if (s.find_first_of(a, 0) != string::npos) { num_words_found++; }
if (s.find_first_of(b, 0) != string::npos) { num_words_found++; }
// none: num_words_found= 0
// one/either: num_words_found= 1
// both: num_words_found= 2
```

Comment: Third error: it will "find" the word "pen" in the line containing two words: "open sesame". That's obviously wrong, too.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Depends on the requirements :-) OP does say "chosen strings" not "chosen words". Certainly something for OP to be aware of !

Comment: Yeah, you have a point, il see how else I can do it.